# Aligning footer image to content area

Tags: html, footer, css

I'm trying to get my footer image to be aligned with the content area above it, but I'm not sure how. I've browsed around and tried out various things such as adding clear:both but to no avail

http://dota-bravery.co.cc/

As you can see the bottom is stuck to the left

Here's the code part with the footer:

```
#footer {
width: 680px;
height: 100px;
margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: -16px ! important;
padding: 30px 0 0 0;
background: url(http://i.imgur.com/q4neu.png) no-repeat;
}

#footer p {
margin: 0;
padding: 0 0 0 40px;
font-size: 77%;
color: #0F1720;
}

#footer a {
color: #0F1720;
}
```

I got the margin-top: -16px there because without it I got a space between content and footer which was fixed by this. Note that the footer was correctly aligned before I put the generator in. Ever since it's been on the left. In case it's helpful I'll also copypaste the rest:

```
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="header">
<h1>{%WebsiteName%}</h1>
<p>{%WebsiteSlogan%}</p>
</div>
<!-- end header -->
<div id="menu">
<h2>Menu</h2>
<ul>
<!--{%menu_start=1%}-->
<li><a href="{%menu_href%}">{%menu_display%}</a></li>
<!--{%menu_end=1%}--> 
</ul>
</div>
<!-- end menu -->
<div id="page">
<div id="content">
<h1 class="title"><span>&nbsp;</span></h1>
<p>{%content%}</p>
</div>
<!-- end content -->
<div style="clear: both;">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
<div id="footer"></div>
<!-- end footer --></div>
<div id="wrapper"></div>
<!-- end wrapper -->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I took the HTML listed here and the CSS from your site and it seems to align OK. http://jsfiddle.net/6x5fQ/ - maybe there is a missing or extra `</div>` in your page's code?

Comment: Looking at your site, you have so many things wrong with your CSS I would highly suggest just starting from scratch and trying to get plain boxes to align in center, THEN style them how you want.  You have different widths throughout, overwriting margins, and more.  Start simple, get it to work, THEN make it look pretty.

Comment: Not just CSS, the HTML is way off too. 2 `<html>`, `<head>`, and `<body>` tags as well

Answer (score 0):

There's a few problems with your code.

You have objects that share the same id (wrapper). That's not allowed. Use classes if you want to apply styles to a few objects.

To fix your problem, you simply need to move your footer so that it is within the first wrapper div (it's outside at the moment, you're closing the wrapper div just before the fotter div - I've tested it, it fixes your problem).

Also, rename the second `wrapper` to something else.

Answer (score 0):

Center the footer:

```
#footer {
    margin: 30px auto 0
}
```

Center the content

```
#wrapper {
    width: 680px;
}
```

You will need to add some additional CSS to fix the inside of the page (width vs padding errors)

Answer (score 0):

This code needs to be seriously looked at. You have more than one `<html>`, `<head>`, and `<body>` tag. Look like a full HTML page where only body content should be. your page is formatted like this - and without correcting that, no realistic trouble shooting can take place whatsoever.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
   ...
</head>
<body>

   ...

    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">   
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
    <head>

       ...
    </head>
    <body onload="generator()">
       ...
    </body>
    </html>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hello, I will have a look at it. I've basically just been editing a template and adding the generator, thanks for the advice

Comment: This isn't advice so much - It's meeting the standard. If your page does not pass an HTML validator - you can be in for any number of unpredictable results. I'm surprised the page looks half-way what you expect it to with all of that invalid code. Use This: http://validator.w3.org/